# Qual o motivo do qual estar dando esse erro "Uncaught ReferenceError: SambaPlayer is not defined"?

Tags: javascript

Está dizendo que "SambaPlayer" não está definido.

```
<script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://api.sambavideos.sambatech.com/v1/medias?access_token=847584758475847874858363&pid=3434&sort=DESC&limit=5&filter=id,title,status,qualifier,description,shortDescription,categoryName,files,thumbs";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    myFunction(url);
    function myFunction(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
        var i;
        var out = "<div>";

        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out += "<a href='#' class='samba-playlist-trigger list-group-item active' data-mediaid=" + arr[i].id + "></a>";
        }
        out += "</div>";
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
</script>

<script>// <![CDATA[
   var player = new SambaPlayer("player", {
   height: 270,
   width: 480,
   playlist: playlistObj,
   playerParams: {
    volume: 0,
    startOutput: '480p',
    html5: true
   },
   events: {
    "*": "eventListener"
   }
   });
// ]]></script>

<script>// <![CDATA[
  function eventListener(player){
  }

  function onClick(mediaId, evt){
    document.getElementsByClassName('samba-playlist-trigger list-group-item active')[0].className = 'samba-playlist-trigger list-group-item';
    evt.target.className = "samba-playlist-trigger list-group-item active";
  }
// ]]></script>
```

O html da página de exibição

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div id="id01"></div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <!-- chamada dos vídeos -->
   <script type="text/javascript" samba-player-api="player" src="http://player.sambatech.com.br/v3/samba.player.api.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Me parece um erro no import da biblioteca. Poderias por gentileza disponibilizar o código HTML do arquivo em que você faz o import das dependências JavaScript?

Comment: Obrigado, Bonifácio. Completei o código html com as chamadas JavaScripts como você solicitou.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: [Samba Player API](http://docs.liquidplatform.com/2011/03/utilizando-o-sambaplayer/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como suspeitei, aparentemente o problema se tratava no import da biblioteca mesmo.

Simulei um cenário parecido com o seu e detectei que o erro que você indicou ocorre se você tentar referenciar o objeto SambaPlayer antes de importar a biblioteca. Isto ocorre porque o JavaScript é executado conforme vai sendo referenciado no HTML, e caso você tente referenciar um objeto antes da biblioteca ser carregada, o erro ocorrerá.

Neste caso você tem duas opções:

Mover o código da chamada ao objeto SambaPlayer para ficar abaixo da chamada da biblioteca:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" samba-player-api="player" src="http://player.sambatech.com.br/v3/samba.player.api.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var player = new SambaPlayer("player", {
  height: 270,
  width: 480,
 playlist: null,
  playerParams: {
    volume: 0,
    startOutput: '480p',
    html5: true
  },
  events: {
    "*": "eventListener"
  }
  });
```

Ou então chamar o objeto SambaPlayer dentro de um document.ready, pois assim o navegador vai esperar até que documento seja carregado para então executar esta parte do JavaScript (e com isto carregar previamente a biblioteca):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function () {
    var player = new SambaPlayer("player", {
      height: 270,
      width: 480,
      playerParams: {
        volume: 0,
        startOutput: '480p',
        html5: true
      },
      events: {
        "*": "eventListener"
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Agora ele acusa outro erro de referência: **Uncaught ReferenceError: playlistObj is not defined** está direcionado a instrução dentro do for: `out += "<a href='#' class='samba-playlist-trigger list-group-item active' data-mediaid=" + arr[i].id + "></a>";`

Comment: O objeto playlistObj não foi definido, este objeto provavelmente armazena as informações da playlist para enviar para a API. Como não tenho conhecimento sobre seu funcionamento, sugiro dar uma olhada na [documentação da API](http://docs.liquidplatform.com/2011/03/utilizando-o-sambaplayer/).

Comment: Já é um direcionamento. Vou revisar essa parte do código. Muito obrigado, Bonifácio!

Comment: De nada @VandréPaulo, boa sorte nos trabalhos, até a próxima!